# Printing squares in difference size next to each other

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

so i have a task to print squares in different sizes, in different areas of the screen. I want each square to be equally far from the other square. As u can see the distance between each square always decrease. This is my result : 
[image: My Result:]

I think the problem is that when i update the `lengthOFside` to `AX`, it doesn't change. Any other tip will be much appreciated :) Here's the code:

```
; multi-segment executable file template.     

newline=160 ;number of chars to move to next line 
col = 2     ;each column is another charachter
lengthOFside = 5 ;side of square, grows each time of the loop
numRow = 5 ;which row to start from
numCol = 30 ;which col to start from
numSquares = 4 ;number of squares


data segment
    ; add your data here!
    pkey db "press any key...$"
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov AX,0B800H
    MOV ES,AX



    ; add your code here  

    ;first print


    MOV DH, numSquares     ;number of squares I want to print
    MOV AX,lengthOFside       
    MOV BL,numRow   ;number line
    MOV BH,numCol   ;num col   
    MOV CX,lengthOFside ;length of one side
    CALL print_square   ;CALL the function that prints the square
    DEC DH


    loopPrint:
    lengthOFside = ax
    ADD BH,lengthOFside+2 ; move right lengthOFside times. 
    ADD AX,2
    MOV CX,AX
    CALL print_square ;print square

    DEC DH
    jnz loopPrint





    lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx

    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h 

    print_square: ;get (x,y) as (bh,bl) and cx = length of one side. Prints a square from that point.                

        MOV SI,0 

        PUSH BX
        CALL Get2startpoint ;get to starting point
        POP BX

        PUSH CX
        CALL  Horizontal_Line  ;print the first horizontal line
        POP CX

        PUSH CX  
        CALL Vertical_Line  ;print the first vertical line
        POP CX  


        PUSH BX
        CALL Get2startpoint   ;return to starting point
        POP BX


        PUSH CX  
        call Vertical_Line    ;print another vertical line
        POP CX  

        PUSH CX
        SUB SI,newline  ;we do because the function vertical line adds new line every END of it's loop. 
                        ;So SI is on the next line so the vertical line will be n+1. so we decrease one line from si
        CALL Horizontal_Line   ;print anohter horizontal line
        POP CX

    RET



    Vertical_Line: 
        ADD SI,newline        ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
        DEC CX                ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
        LOOP2:                ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
        MOV ES:[SI],'*'       ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
        ADD si,newline        ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
        LOOP LOOP2            ;prints vertical line adds to si 160 after printing *
    RET

    Horizontal_Line:          ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        MOV ES:[SI],'*'       ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        DEC CX                ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        LOOP1:                ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        ADD SI,2              ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        MOV ES:[SI],'*'       ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
        LOOP LOOP1            ;add si,2 to get to the next data cell and insert * 
    RET    

    Get2startpoint:             ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        MOV SI,0                ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        ADD_NEW_LINE:           ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        ADD SI,newline          ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        DEC BL                  ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        JNZ ADD_NEW_LINE        ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
                                ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        SKIP_TO_COL:            ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        ADD SI,col              ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        DEC BH                  ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
        JNZ SKIP_TO_COL         ;gets (x,y) as <bh,bl> and gets to the point where it should start printing the square
    RET        








ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: Your comments hurt my eyes! :) Anyway, use a debugger to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Jester problem is, I can't figure out how to debug in my software. And yeah those comments hurt me as well :)

Comment: http://courses.ee.sun.ac.za/OLD/2003/Rekenaarstelsels245/8086_Instruksies/emulator.html

Comment: The right side of the panel is actually the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ADD BH,lengthOFside+2 ; move right lengthOFside times.
> ```

This always moves the same amount to the right because *lengthOFside* has a fixed value of 5!
Make the addition relative to the *current* length of the side that is in the `AX` register:

```
add     bh, al
add     bh, 2
add     ax, 2
```

Shorter:

```
add     ax, 2
add     bh, al
```

Comment: But this solution is only valid for the 128 first squares right? Because of will take the 8 low bits of `AX` register

Comment: @user6219654, how many squares do you expect to generate? Aren't you considering the screen size? This answer is **correct** because it gives the proper separation between each square, so you should click the checkmark ✔ to accept it.

Comment: I didnt say it was wrong I'm just trying to understand whether I understood it correctly